Flutter syncfusion date range circle not in center
daterangepicker image i want to ask how to make this circle place in center of the date,
here is my code
showDialog(
              barrierDismissible: false,
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Dialog(
                   child: SfDateRangePicker(),
                   );
              },
);


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I tried to run your code in a real android device and it's working perfectly

SOLVED, i upgrade the version from
syncfusion_flutter_datepicker: 20.4.44
to
syncfusion_flutter_datepicker: 23.1.44

@RandalSchwartz why can we use it even though we haven't paid for it?, do you have any alternative for date range picker besides syncfusion?

You are subject to the release license.  Please read the license carefully.

This issue is already fixed, and the fix has been published in the version 22.1.36. Therefore, to avoid this issue, upgrade the syncfusion_flutter_charts package to the latest version below.
Version: https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker/versions/25.2.7
